# Using content type fields within page.html.twig

Tags: theming

I am new to Drupal 8, and relatively new to Drupal templating in general.

Here's what I am trying to do:
I have a content type, called "Property" with a "header_color" field.  When I add a property, I set the color that I want for that property's header.
When I then navigate to that node, the background color of the page's header would be whatever I set the color to.

My understanding is that this needs to take place in page.html.twig, and that there is a way to grab the data from the content type and use it within page.html.twig, using:

`{{ node.field_header_color.value }}`.

This is the tag I have in my page.html.twig:

```
<header id="header" class="header" role="banner" aria-label="{{ 'Site header'|t }}" style='background-color:{{ node.field_header_color.value }}'>
```

When I inspect it in the Chrome Dev, it shows:

`"style='background-color:''"`

Can someone give me some guidance on what I am doing wrong here?

I am using Drupal 8.6.4

Comment: You should preprocess this, `node` won't always exist in the context of page.html.twig. For example, the user login page, a webform, a Views page.. anyway, when you made this change, did you clear the cache? If what you are viewing is a node object, then the node object _should_ exist.

Comment: Make sure you clear the cache after twig changes, and then maybe try placing `{{ dump() }}` in your twig file, this will dump out all the variables you have access to.

Comment: Thanks, using dump() helped me nail down the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the preprocess_page set up the variable

```
if (($node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node')) && $node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
 $variables['bg_color'] = $node->field_header_color->value;
```

}
     and use this in ur twig file

```
<header id="header" class="header" role="banner" aria-label="{{ 'Site header'|t }}" style='background-color:{{bg_color}}'>
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The one thing I had to change was I used $variables['bg_color'] instead of just $bg_color.

Comment: Sorry Me bad, Adding that to my answer